# How do I show that there are integers $x, y$ with $[a, b]$ = $ax + by$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, least-common-multiple

I've seen the answer for gcd$(a,b)$ but never for the lcm$(a,b)$?

Comment: Just take $x=[a,b]/a$ and $y=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lcm$(a,b)$, it's a multiple of $a$, so we can take $x=\frac{lcm(a,b)}{a}, y=0$. The gcd case, as you can see, is more interesting.

Comment: I'm looking for a more general proof rather than a specific example. How can I show that it's the case or any $x$ and $y$?

Comment: How can you show what's the case? I'm confused as to what you're trying to get.

Comment: Sorry I'll rephrase. I'm trying to show that the lowest common multiple of $[a,b]$ can be expressed as $ax+by$ for some integers $x,y$. By the looks of your initial answer it's a specific case where $y=0$ but how can I show a more general case?

Comment: @K.M. I showed that it can be expressed as $ax+by$ for a pair of integers $x,y$ that I gave (one of them happens to be $0$). Are you looking for **all** pairs?

Comment: I guess you could say it's all pairs but I like to call it a general case because all pairs sounds like a literal list of all possibly pairs whereas I just mean proving that regardless of what $x,y$ you have. The case holds.

Comment: @K.M. What exactly would you like to prove? Do you want to find a parametric expression for all pairs of $(x,y)$ that satisfy this? Do you want to find a way to calculate a pair $(x,y)$ so that $ax+by=c$ for some $c$ given from $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Well this actually follows from the answer for the gcd. Here's a big hint, suppose x' and y' are such that gcd(a,b) = ax'+by'. Now, we know the gcd divides both a and b and that lcm is divisible by both a and b. So try working from there toward a solution.

Comment: I can't see where to go from here. I've written down 4 divisor's side by side and I'm just starring at them blankly. Help!